# dimension and shapes python

Tags: python, valueerror

*I'm trying to plot the results but I'm getting an error of dimension and shapes*

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

c = 4
k = 2
m = 20
F = 5
 
Ts = 0.1 # Sampling Time
Tstart = 0 # End of Simulation Time
Tstop = 60
N = int(Tstop-Tstart/Ts) # Simulation length
x1 = np.zeros(N+2)
x2 = np.zeros(N+2)
x1 [0] = 0
x2 [0] = 0
 
a11 = 1
a12 = Ts
a21 = -(Ts*k)/m
a22 = 1 - (Ts*c)/m

b1 = 0
b2 = Ts/m


for k in range(N+1):
   x1[k+1] = a11 * x1[k] + a12 * x2[k] + b1 + F
   x2[k+1] = a21 * x1[k] + a22 * x2[k] + b2 + F



 
t = np.arange(Tstart,Tstop+2*Ts,Ts)

plt.plot(t,x1)
plt.plot(t,x2)
```

> ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (602,) and (62,)

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea if it is the right way of doing that, but the code below runs without an error. The main change was done to `t = np.arange(Tstart,Tstop+2*Ts,Ts)` eliminating `Ts` as step of range as this caused the ten times larger values for the axis.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

c = 4
k = 2
m = 20
F = 5
 
Ts     = 0.1             # Sampling Time
Tstart = 0               # End of Simulation Time
Tstop  = 60
N = int(Tstop-Tstart/Ts) # Simulation length
print(f'{N=}')
x1 = np.zeros(N+1)
x2 = np.zeros(N+1)
x1 [0] = 0
x2 [0] = 0
 
a11 = 1
a12 = Ts
a21 = -(Ts*k)/m
a22 = 1 - (Ts*c)/m

b1 = 0
b2 = Ts/m


for k in range(N):
   x1[k+1] = a11 * x1[k] + a12 * x2[k] + b1 + F
   x2[k+1] = a21 * x1[k] + a22 * x2[k] + b2 + F

# t = np.arange(Tstart, Tstop+2*Ts, Ts)
# N = int(Tstop-Tstart/Ts) # Simulation length
# x1 = np.zeros(N+2)

t = np.arange(Tstart, Tstop+1*Ts) #

plt.plot(t,x1)
plt.plot(t,x2)

plt.show()
```

showing following plot:

[image]